# Codeigniter and jquery Ajax method with Sever side validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using **Codeigniter** with **jquery** ajax call, What I want is:
to show the error message from Codeigniter own form_validation errors.

I am using jquery `$.ajax` method and getting the form values by clicking on `sumbit` button, which is handled in `formhander.js` file.

I am always given `if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)` in this condition, when I submit the form by **jquery** ajax method.

My Controller file: ajaxcontroller.php is as follow:

```php
class AjaxController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('FName', 'First Name', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[50]');
        $response = array('Code' => 500, 'Message' => NULL);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('ajax_form');
        } else {
            $FirstName = $this->input->post('FName');

            if ($FirstName != '') {
                $response['Code'] = 200;
                $response['Message'] = 'Thank you, ' . $FirstName .'For your form submission using jquery ajax';
            } else {
                $response['Code'] = 500;
                $response['Message'] = 'You must fill your NAME field';
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
```

My View file: ajax_view.php is as follow:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is testing of jQuery Ajax</title>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/testjs/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/testjs/formhandler.js');?>"></script>
        <style>
            div.invalid {
                color: red;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <form method="post" id="MyForm" name="MyForm">
            First Name:<input type="text" id="FName" name="FName" /><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

My jquery ajax file: `formhander.js` is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function handleform() {
        $("#submit").live('click',function(){

            var fName = $("#FName").val();
            var data ='FName='+fName;

            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/ci/index.php/ajaxcontroller/index",
                data: data,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(obj){
                    if(obj.Code) 
                        $("#output").html(obj.Message);
                    else 
                        $("#output").html(obj.Message);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });    
    }
});
```

What I get when I click on the submit button is whole view file, but I want to show the codeigniter form_validation error messages when I submit the form using jquery ajax method.

Let me know if I am not doing it correctly or if it is not possible.

Comment: `$this->load->view('ajax_form');` you are returning the whole view.Just return the error message

Comment: if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('ajax_form');
        }
You know in codeigniter, this condition check to see if the form is submitted for first time, or if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible alright, I believe it is the jQuery `serialize()` method that is missing in your ajax call, it is meant for form processing and I got quite a few errors before when I sent ajax form requests. So instead of

```
var fName = $("#FName").val();
data: data, // ajax call
```

replace it with:

```
var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
 data: formData, // ajax call
```

I'm quite sure it'll do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried that as well, but it doesn't work, what I actually wanted is that I want to submit my form by jquery $.ajax method, but at Server side I want codeigniter validation, you know what I mean?

Comment: If you want codeigniter validation then you should echo it, aka echo validation_errors() or form_error(fieldName), is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have already echoed it in my view file, but you know that method only works when form is submitted or page is refreshed, but it won't work in case of jquery $.ajax method, did you get what I really want?

Comment: It does work with ajax my friend, try to serialize the form and echo validation_errors in response, it should be working!

Answer (score 0):

Your `formhander.js` look strange, as you are defining a function in the `$(document).ready()` handler, without calling it.

In consequense the `#submit.click` handler is not attached to the button and nothing is intercepting the click.

You should correct you javascript ( I would recommend removing the `function handleform()` definition )

---

You cannot submit directly to the CodeIgniter controller, as CodeIgniter is generating the form tag for you in the view and perhaps also including some extra hidden input.
Include the javascript from your view, then your controller should behave as desired, but you my also want to touch the data posted to have a normal controller behavior if the user disable javascript.

Corrected `formhander.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /// attaching event handler to the form submit event
    $("form#myForm").submit(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        var url=this.action;
        $.post( // use of the shorhand function
            url,
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(obj) {
                console.log(obj) // you should check this one
                if(obj.code == 200 ) {
                ...
                }else{
                ...
                }
            },
            "json"
        );
        return false;
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for pointing out. but this I am not getting what I really wanted.

Comment: is your php class as written in the question or does it also have extra `<?php` at the beginning ?

Comment: I am getting values from jquery ajax call and everything correctly, what I need I want without page refresh and get $this->form_validation->set_rules(); errors in my view file.

Comment: Yes. I did. but I wanted to know that CI validation error and without page refresh, but that's not possible.

Comment: You cannot directly post to the CI controller, your need to generate the view and extract the post URL and extra parameter generated by `<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>` from the form with javascript, then your controller should be able to validate, I will correct the javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have made several modifications on your program:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AjaxController extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index(){
        $this->load->view('ajax_form');
}

function clicked(){
        $FirstName = $this->input->post('FName');

        if ($FirstName != '') {
            $response['Code'] = 200;
            $response['Message'] = 'Thank you, ' . $FirstName .'For your form submission using jquery ajax';
        } else {
            $response['Code'] = 500;
            $response['Message'] = 'You must fill your NAME field';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);


}

}
```

In your controller, I separated the loading of your ajax_form view to your ajax function, note: ajax and code igniter form validations will not work together because CI form validation needs to refresh the page in order to display the result of the validation.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//function handleform() { //removed the function handleform() because you will no longer need it, and you are not calling it in the first place.
    $("#submit").on('click',function(){ //replace live with on. 
    var fName = $("#FName").val();
    var data ='FName='+fName;

    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/ci/index.php/AjaxController/clicked",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj){

            //if(obj.Code == 200) //Note: if Statements only evaluates if it is true or false. you did not compare obj.Code to anything, and obj.Code is not true nor false
            //{
                alert(obj.Message); //Note: I have removed your if condition because you will no longer need it. The message you sent from the server to client is already evaluated, there is no need to re-evaluate it in the client.
                //$("#output").html(obj.Message); output element is not found here, so i just alerted your message
            //}

            //else
            //{
                //alert(obj.Message);
                //$("#output").html(obj.Message);
            //} 

        }
    });
    //return false; you don't need to return anything here.
   });    
//}
   });
</script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>This is testing of jQuery Ajax</title>
    <style>
        div.invalid {
            color: red;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        First Name:<input type="text" id="FName" name="FName" /><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</body>
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated, so you should use `on`.
Notice That I removed the `<form>` tag, because when you click an input button with type `submit` it will trigger a page refresh..

Comment: thank you for separating, which I have tried it as well, but you mean that CI validation doesn't work in case I am using jquery $.ajax method, Did you mean that?

Comment: thank you clearing that and pointing out all the misconception, but that means we can't use jquery with CI as correctly as we wanted?

Comment: CI is flexible, but some of the functions like the form_validation is built in a manner that requires page refresh in order to display the validation result, form_validation is only written in PHP, but you are using AJAX which does not need any page refresh in order to work, because it was designed to be that way. transmitting data from client to server vice versa without interrupting the view.

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('FName', 'First Name', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[50]'); you can handle this type of validation in the controller without relying on code_igniter validations if you want to use AJAX.

Comment: Yes. I know that, but codeigniter make it easy to filter data, as CI have many useful method, like xss_clean, required, alpha etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73994/discussion-between-arzgethalm-and-kashif-ullah).